# SQL Server : display multiple rows in one row and multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, multiple-columns

I've found similar questions but nothing that has a solution I've been able to make work for me. I've been out of practice and stuck on this.

I have a table that tracks employee positions. Each employee can have any number of active positions. I want to display each employee as a single record with all their positions in that record spanning multiple columns.

A glance at the data shows that there are no employees with more than 6 active positions and since this is a one-time query, I should be able to work with that number.

The positions all have a sequence number assigned but they're not in a nice handy order - inactive positions for an employee retain the sequence number.

So right now I have something that looks like this:

```
    ID | Name | Title | Cat | Seq
    ------------------------------
    10 | John | Asst. | HR  | 13
    10 | John | Tutor | EDU | 17
    11 | Sue  | Mgr   | PA  | 6
    11 | Sue  | Adj.  | EDU | 7
    11 | Sue  | Tutor | EDU | 13
    ...
    11 | Sue  | Asst. | HR  | 22
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
    ID | Name | Title 1 | Cat 1 | Title 2 | Cat 2 | Title 3...| Title 6 | Cat 6
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    10 | John | Asst.   | HR    | Tutor   | EDU   | NULL      | NULL    | NULL
    11 | Sue  | Mgr.    | PA    | Adj.    | EDU   | Tutor     | Asst.   | HR
```

Let me know what additional information I need to provide.

Comment: You're probably going to end up in the realm of `PIVOT`s, they can be a little hard to work with in the context of what you're trying to do, especially if you try to generate a dynamic number of columns. This kind of goes against the principles of RDBMS because you're denormalizing your data.

Comment: Ugh, I was afraid pivot would be the suggestion. re: Denormalizing, it's just for a one-time data dump so it's not a problem in this case.

Comment: If it's a onetime thing, I would suggest adding a column `ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Cat, Title)`, then you can use that as an index in Excel or some other spreadsheet program to transpose them.

Comment: [So, did my answer solve your problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of row_number and pivots to do this. Using SQL Server 2012+ the query could look something like below. It's a bit messy, but it should get the job done, although there might be better ways to accomplish the same result.

```
select 
    id
    , name
    , max([Title 1]) as [Title 1]
    , max([Cat 1])   as [Cat 1]
    , max([Title 2]) as [Title 2]
    , max([Cat 2])   as [Cat 2]
    , max([Title 3]) as [Title 3]
    , max([Cat 3])   as [Cat 3]
    -- and so on for the remaining columns...
from (
    select 
       id, name, title, cat
       , t = concat('Title ',row_number() over (partition by id order by seq)) 
       , c = concat('Cat ',row_number() over (partition by id order by seq)) 
    from your_table
    ) src
pivot ( max(title) for t in ([title 1],[title 2],[title 3]) )pt
pivot ( max(cat)   for c in ([cat 1],[cat 2],[cat 3]) )pc
group by id, name;
```

I only wrote out title/cat 1 through 3 to save some space but you should get the idea.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6fc77/1)

Sample result:

```
| id | name | Title 1 | Cat 1 | Title 2 | Cat 2 | Title 3 |  Cat 3 |
|----|------|---------|-------|---------|-------|---------|--------|
| 10 | John |   Asst. |   HR  |   Tutor |   EDU |  (null) | (null) |
| 11 |  Sue |   Mgr   |   PA  |   Adj.  |   EDU |   Tutor |    EDU |
```